# Separating the value of the rows in the table

Tags: php, mysql, yii2

I am planning to put a query into my variable but my problem is I need to group a different set of values to separate them in my PHP output I am wondering if this is possible, even help with the SQL query would be a big help. See my screenshot:
[image]

If you look at the bottom of the table `section` column you will see that there is a `GI21` and `GI122`. Now when the query I am using right now is this.

```
SELECT `scstock`.*, `schead`.* FROM `scstock` LEFT JOIN `schead` ON schead.TrNo = scstock.TrNo WHERE (`schead`.`curriculumcode`='BSIT 2011') AND (`schead`.`styear`='4') AND (`schead`.`terms`='1ST') AND (`schead`.`isBlock`=1)
```

or in Yii

```
->select(['scstock.*', 'schead.*'])
    ->leftJoin('schead', 'schead.TrNo = scstock.TrNo')
    ->where(['schead.curriculumcode' => $curriculumcode,
              'schead.styear' => $year,
              'schead.terms' => $term,
              'schead.isBlock' => 1
              ])
    ->asArray()
    ->all();
```

That will output all the rows the has `isBlock = 1` but what I need to do is to separate  `GI21` and `GI122`, maybe put them in an array like right now but maybe there is a better implementation but right now after putting them in an array I return them to be put in the view in a table like this.

```
 <table class="table table-bordered" id="studentTable">
              <th>Subject</th>
              <th>Schedule</th>
              <th>Section</th>
              <th>Action</th>
              <th>Slots</th>
              <th>Status</th>
          <?php foreach($getBlock as $values): ?>

                  <tr>
                    <td><?= $values['subjectcode']; ?></td>
                    <td><?= $values['schedday'] . ' ' . $values['schedtime'] ?></td>
                    <td><?= $values['section'] ?></td>
                    <td><?= '....' ?></td>
                    <td><?= $values['slots'] ?></td>
                    <td><?= '....' ?></td>
                  </tr>

          <?php endforeach; ?>
              </table>
```

Now to separate them in the view maybe I'll just put the `foreach` in the `table` tag to separate the sections?**How do I group a different set of values to separate them in my PHP output?** Any kind of help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use two separated  query  one for not (G121 and GI122) eg: getBlock1

```
->select(['scstock.*', 'schead.*'])
    ->leftJoin('schead', 'schead.TrNo = scstock.TrNo')
    ->where(['schead.curriculumcode' => $curriculumcode,
              'schead.styear' => $year,
              'schead.terms' => $term,
              'schead.isBlock' => 1,
              'not in','schead.section',['G121', 'GI122'],
              ])
    ->asArray()
    ->all();
```

and second with in (G121 and GI122) eg: getBlock2

```
where(['not in','attribute',$array]);



->select(['scstock.*', 'schead.*'])
    ->leftJoin('schead', 'schead.TrNo = scstock.TrNo')
    ->where(['schead.curriculumcode' => $curriculumcode,
              'schead.styear' => $year,
              'schead.terms' => $term,
              'schead.isBlock' => 1,
              'in','schead.section',['G121', 'GI122'],
              ])
    ->asArray()
    ->all();
```

the you can related in a first foreach to $getBlock1 and  in a second foreach at $getBlock2